# How to make authenticated django rest api call from android client?

Tags: java, android, django-rest-framework, restful-authentication

I am making an android app which has a django rest api as the backend and want to make authenticated network calls using the token given to the user when he/she has logged in.

I am using retrofit to make requests to the backend. Here is what I am doing right now to attempt to make an authenticated network call to the rest api.

```
@Override
public void loadAllUsers() {
    Call<List<User>> call = userServiceApi.loadAllUsers();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<User>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<List<User>> call, @NonNull Response<List<User>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                List<User> users = response.body();
                eventBus.post(new LoadAllUsersEvent(users));
            } else {
                eventBus.post(new FailLoadAllUsersEvent());
                Log.d(TAG, response.message());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<List<User>> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
            eventBus.post(new LoadUsersUnreachableServerEvent());
            Log.d(TAG, t.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the retrofit interface relevant to this api request:

```
@GET("users/")
Call<List<User>> loadAllUsers(@Header("Authorization: Token ") Token token);
```

When I make this call passing the user's token in as the header, I get status code 401: Unauthenticated: "GET /users/ HTTP/1.1" 401 58

What am I doing wrong for django rest [Token Authentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication) to work and to make an authenticated django rest api call?

Comment: Are you using OkHttp as well?

Comment: No I am not using OkHttp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quick fix for this would be to change your api interface:

```
@GET("users/")
Call<List<User>> loadAllUsers(@Header("Authorization") Token token);
```

Value you are passing in should be formated as `"Token %s"`.

This is not a very good solution, because you'd have to pass the token around to all of your api calls.

Better way to solve your authorization issues is by using [OkHttp client](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) and implement authenticator, which takes care of everything for you.

OkHttp and Retrofit work together very well.

Comment: This is a good one https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-how-to-use-okhttp-3-with-retrofit-1, but it's for retrofit 1. The only difference is that  RestAdapter was renamed to Retrofit. Of course I suggest using the latest versions of OkHttp and Retrofit.

Comment: So should the authentication header contain "Token %s" instead of "Authorization" because I have implemented that with OkHttp and it says "Unexpected char 0x20 in 5 in header name: Token %s" @Andrej Jurkin

Comment: Hey Tom, headers are key-value pair. Key is "Authorization" value is what you pass into your retrofit interface and the string should be "Token 0b79bab50daca910b000d4f1a2b675d604257e42". Something like that.

Comment: Now I get another error. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $. It runs the onFailure method instead of onResponse

Comment: This means your request goes through and fails when parsing. Your authentication problem has been solved. Please close the question and continue seeking answers elsewhere.